# PowerDesigner constraint name, how to default to lower case

Tags: powerdesigner

I want all my tables, columns and references in the PDM to be generated as lower case values in the SQL scripts.

Tools > Model Options > Naming convention has been set to lower case for all the objects, but for some reason the primary key constraint name is defaulting to uppercase.

Is there a section of the menu that specifically sets the primary key that I am missing?

The Table Preview tab indicates all except the keys are being lower cased

I don't know what menu option I am missing I've tried all related to the model settings.

Example:

```
create table mtm_orders2customers (
   objid                SERIAL               not null,
   entry_date           DATE                 null,
   order_id             INT4                 null,
   customer_id          INT4                 null,
   payment_status       VARCHAR(1000)        null,
   order_status         VARCHAR(500)         null,
   order_total          DECIMAL(12,2)        null,
   tax_due              DECIMAL(12,2)        null,
   shipping_fee         DECIMAL(12,2)        null,
   constraint PK_MTM_ORDERS2CUSTOMERS primary key (objid)
);
```

Comment: For which DBMS are you generating your Physical Model?

Answer (score 0):

I tried with an Oracle Physical Model.

Looking in the DBMS, under `ORACLE Version 18c::Script\Objects\PKey\ConstName`, I see `PK_%.U27:TABLE%`.

If I change it to `pk_%TABLE%`, I'm closer to a lowercase primary key constraint name.

Same with `ORACLE Version 18c::Script\Objects\Key\ConstName`.

Comment: Ah. I'm doing it for Postgres. I'll check there. Thanks.